# How to detect Iframe video has ended in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, iframe

How can I detect that the iframe playing video has ended suppose I have below iframe

```
<iframe title="vimeo-player" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/185829586" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

here, I want to call a function when this video ended.
How can I achieve  this.
Your help would be great for me
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Vimeo Player API](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js).

```
npm i -S @vimeo/player
```

Simple Vimeo player component:

```jsx
function VimeoPlayer({
    onEnded = () => {},
    ...attrs
}) {
    const ref = useRef(null);

    useEffect(
        () => {
            const player = new Vimeo.Player(ref.current);

            player.on('ended', onEnded);

            return () => {
                player.off('ended', onEnded);
            };
        },
        []
    );

    return (
        <iframe
            ref={ref}
            {...attrs}
        />
    );
}
```

Usage example:

```jsx
<VimeoPlayer
    title="vimeo-player"
    src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/185829586"
    width={640}
    height={360}
    frameBorder="0"
    allowFullScreen
    onEnded={() => {
        // Do something here when the video ends...
    }}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the your reply, but here   I m getting whole iframe from server then converting it inot HTML so how can I add onEnded event here `<iframe title="vimeo-player" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/185829586" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: Your question is tagged **reactjs**, is it not? See the link in the answer. It will tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: Yes, my question related reacts,js but as I told you I am getting  a  whole built iframe  so can't  figure out  how can I add event here.

Comment: OK. Just see the link in the answer. It’s not specific to React.

Comment: here I have reproduced can you help me with https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qwodpj

Answer (score 0):

you can use react-player it is far better for implementation than Vimeo. It can take any type of URL and have **onEnded** attribute readily available.

`**npm install react-player**`

import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'

// Render a YouTube video player

```
 <ReactPlayer playing muted onEnded={callBack}  width="450px" height="100%" url='https://www.youtube.com/embed/_Z8RKEyda2w' />
```

[package details can be found here for react-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player)